# Generate table with character values

Tags: r

I created this data frame which contain one column with 100 rows.

```
DATA<-data.frame(
  kind_l = as.character(sample(x=c("PL","FL"), prob = c(.8, .2),size=100,replace=TRUE)))

 str(DATA)

'data.frame':   10000 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ kind_l: Factor w/ 2 levels "FL","PL": 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
```

So this lines of code generate data frame with factor values (although I use command as.charcter)  I can convert with additional line of code into character with code below:

```
    DATA$kind_l<-as.character(DATA$kind_l)
    str(DATA)

'data.frame':   10000 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ kind_l: chr  "FL" "PL" "PL" "PL" ...
```

So can anybody help how to generate first table DATA with character not with factor ?

Comment: The `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` inside `data.frame()` should not solve it?

Comment: Please update to new `R` version.  It would be by default `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Comment: What version of R are you using? The argument `stringsAsFactors ` has been changed to FALSE for R 4.0.0

Comment: Thank you is works !!!